# enabled/disable checkbox based on object property in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am generating an array of objects and then Outputting these into a list, each objects has a checkbox that then adds it to the `changeableElements` array if it is checked

I am having trouble getting it to show only objects that are added to the array to appear as checked, and also disabled all of the other checkboxes once 3 are selected, how can I do this?

```
             const [items, setItems] = useState(
               [...Array(301)].map(
                    (_, i) => ({ name: `element ${i}`, selected: false, id: `element_uid_${i}}` }),
                 ),
                   )
             const [changeableElements, setchangeableElements] = useState([])
             const updatechangeableElements = (item) => {
              setchangeableElements(changeableElements.concat(item))
             }

                    <ElementsListWrap>
          {items.slice(0, itemsLimit !== null ? itemsLimit : Infinity)
          .filter((item) => new RegExp(`^${searchValue.toLowerCase()}`).test(item.name))
          .map((item) => (
            <div
              key={item.name}
            >
              {console.log('bkakask',changeableElements.filter((i) => item.id === i.id))}
              <ElementWrap>
                <Checkbox
                  key={item.name}
                  onChange={() => updatechangeableElements({ ...item, selected: true })}
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={changeableElements.filter(i => item.id === i.selected === true).length > 0}
                  disabled={items.filter((i) => i.selected).length > 2 && item.selected !== true}
                />
                {console.log(changeableElements.map(bla => item.id === bla.id))}
                {item.name}
              </ElementWrap>
            </div>
            ),
          )}
        </ElementsListWrap>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `checked` to the result of `filter` which will always be an array (*sometimes empty*), so always truthy.

You likely need to use something like this

```
    <Checkbox
       key={item.name}
       onChange={() => updatechangeableElements({ ...item, selected: true })}
       type="checkbox"
       checked={changeableElements.find(i => item.id === i && item.selected === true)}
       disabled={items.filter((i) => i.selected).length > 2 && item.selected !== true}
    />
```

---

**update**

This should handle both checked and disabled states.

```js
.map((item) => {
    const isChecked = item.selected && changeableElements.some(i => item.id === i);
    const isDisabled = !isChecked && (items.filter((i) => i.selected).length > 2);
    return (
      <div
        key={item.name}
      >
        <ElementWrap>
          <Checkbox
            key={item.name}
            onChange={() => updatechangeableElements({ ...item, selected: true })}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={isChecked}
            disabled={isDisabled}
          />
          {item.name}
        </ElementWrap>
      </div>
      )},
```

Comment: I suggest using `array::find` instead as it does return a truthy value if found, `undefined` if not. Also, `selected` is already a boolean, so checking it against `true` is redundant, but at this point I think the OP could simply check *just* the `selected` value. Not really sure what's going on with the array as mapping isn't overt.

Comment: @DrewReese even better (*this way it will stop traversing the array once it finds an item, so better performance as well*). Updated answer.

Comment: I have updated the code to include how im mapping my array, thanks for the answer, the checking works now however the checkboxes are not disabled when over 3 are selected

Comment: @tomharrison updated answer with what i believe should handle both cases

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` does not return boolean, and checkbox is checked if `checked` property is true.

So you might want change the checked section to:

```
checked={changeableElements.filter(item => item.id === item.selected === true).length > 0}
```

Instead of:

```
checked={changeableElements.filter(item => item.id === item.selected === true)}
```

For disable issue, have you map the items? Or you only render each object in the array? If you only render one item in the array, the condition will never be met.